# Most efficient way of combining two big lists

Tags: java

I have two lists that each contain 2500 values.

```
List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I need to combine these two lists into a two dimensional list or any other appropriate data structure that allows me to only iterate through once rather than doing the operation below which is very slow when dealing with big lists:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
    for (int in = 0; in < data.size(); in++) {

       }
 }
```

It's critical the index of each list match each other when combining these two lists. So `headers.get(9);` must match `data.get(9);`.

I need a new list or other data structure that will allow me to store each value in the two lists as pairs. So `headers.get(0);` would be paired with `data.get(0);`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you mean by "must match"? Equals? Some common property is the same? Most similar value of common property? What would you do if there is no match?

Comment: @AndyTurner I need a new list or some other data structure that will allow me to store each value in the two lists as pairs. So headers.get(0) would be paired with data.get(0).

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) { headers.get(i) ... data.get(i) ... }`.

Comment: instead of doing headers.get(0) with data.get(0) you should create an object that has a field "header" and a field "data" and make a list of the object, then you can do list.get(0).getHeader and list.get(0).getData. hope this helps.

Comment: @isaace that is not main issue for me. I only used headers.get(0) with data.get(0) to explain I need the values paired. The real issue for me is how to pair values from big lists in an efficient way.

Comment: to add 2500 records to a list isn't a big deal. use the loop in @KalaBalik 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new class:

```
class HeadersWithData{
    String header;
    String data;

    HeadersWithData(String header, String data){
        this.header = header;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Declare your list:

```
List<HeadersWithData> combinedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And fill the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++){
    combinedList.add(new HeadersWithData(headers.get(i), data.get(i)));
}
```

Note: This is a *one*-dimensional list. A two-dimensional list would not make any sense in your case.

Answer (score 2):

About

> It's critical the index of each list match each other when combining these two lists.

Create a simple class to hold both value

```
class MyData{
    String header;
    String data;
}
```

Then use a single `List<MyData>`. You will only have one `List` of 2500 items.

Based on what you do with those data, other collection could be more efficient to read, but not to update.

Comment: This is good approach to pair the values form each list but main issue I was facing was finding a way to pair values from big lists in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the one list to contain the same pairs that you'd get doing the nested loop, there's nothing you can do.  You're iterating over 2500*2500=6250000 pairs.  Nothing will make that fast.  Iterating over one list instead of the nested for loops will not make a difference.

If you don't want to iterate over every combination of elements from both lists, but iterate over one list once and then iterate over the other list once, then that's equivalent to doing one for loop after the other, not one for loop inside of the other.  And *that* will be fast whether you combine them into one big list, or iterate over one list and then the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if the loop you presented is what what you really wanted to archieve, but if you wanted every element of the first list correspond to exactly one element of the second list I would suggest using `Map<String, String>`. This allows you to map every element of the first list of strings to one elements of the second list. Each pair is then stored as an `Map.Entry<Key,Value>`.

That way you are able to iterate only once through the map using for example loop like this:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {...}
```